# Cannot find gsl header files when compiling

Tags: libraries

I am completely new to Linux. I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on an old PC and I am trying to install the gsl library for a project. I ran

```
sudo apt install libgsl2, libgsl0-dev, libgsl-dev, gsl-bin
```

Then I made a `gsltest.c` test program with the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl_randist.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  /* set up GSL RNG */
  gsl_rng *r = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_mt19937);
  /* end of GSL setup */

  int i,n;
  double gauss,gamma;  

  n=atoi(argv[1]);
  for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      gauss=gsl_ran_gaussian(r,2.0);
      gamma=gsl_ran_gamma(r,2.0,3.0);
      printf("%2.4f %2.4f\n", gauss,gamma);
    }
  return(0);
}
```

I copied the code from somewhere on the internet and proceeded with the following command

```
gcc -Wall -I/home/myname/gsl/include -c gsltest.c
```

which throws an error:

```
gsltest.c:2:21: fatal error: gsl_rng.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does `cc gsltest.c -o gsltest` work? I assume `/usr/include/gsl/gsl_rng.h` is present, because you mention installing the relevant package.

Comment: `cc gsltest.c -o gsltest` did not work but when I checked in the GUI the file was present...

Answer (score 4):

If you installed `libgsl-dev`, then the headers should be in `/usr/include/gsl/`, hence the compiler should be able to locate them if you specify `-I/usr/include/gsl`

**Or** you can omit the `-I` directive altogether if you change your #includes to `#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>` etc.

Alternatively, you might want to consider using `pkg-config` to locate the headers automatically e.g.

```
gcc -Wall `pkg-config --cflags gsl` -c gsltest.c
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you so much!
I added the `gsl/gsl...` to my includes, omitted the `-I` part and then went ahead with the command `$ gcc -L/usr/local/lib example.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm'` which worked!